# System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException Not handled by user code in query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've got a method inside of my `DataController.cs`:

```
public JsonResult MoveInLogin(LoginData d)
{
    using (MoveInDBEntities dm = new MoveInDBEntities())
    {
        var user = dm.MoveIns.Where(a => a.CID.Equals(d.CID) && a.Email.Equals(d.Email)).FirstOrDefault();
        return new JsonResult { Data = user, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

On that 4th line where the user is declared, is where this exception gets triggered:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

As I looked in further, I noticed that Exception Details are:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The data types text and varchar
>   are incompatible in the equal to operator.

My column name CID is of type `varchar(10)` and Email is of type `text` in the SQL database.

How can I format my query to get rid of this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Email is of type text in the SQL database

In your statement you are comparing the Email property as a parameter to the Email property contained in the column which is text. The Email property is probably being parameterized to a `varchar` type and sql statement is failing because the generated statement is probably `@email = Email` where `@email` is of type `varchar` and Email is `text`.

Type `text` is also obsolete ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)), Microsoft prefers everyone now use `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)` for ntext. Converting the sql type in your database to `varchar(max)` will solve the problem and would be the best approach.

You should look at your type mappings as you might be able to specify that Email is actually type `Text` but even that would probably fail because I do not believe sql type `text` can be compared or searched (maybe I am wrong).

---

Recreate Error

```
create table #MoveIns (
CID varchar(10) not null,
Email text not null)

insert into #MoveIns (CID, Email) values('1','email 1')
, ('2','email 2')

declare @cid varchar(10) = '1', @email varchar(2000) ='email 1'

/*Next line has error: The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.*/
select * from #MoveIns where @cid = CID AND @email = Email

drop table #MoveIns
```

Fix Error

```
create table #MoveIns (
CID varchar(10) not null,
Email text not null)

insert into #MoveIns (CID, Email) values('1','email 1')
, ('2','email 2')

/*This statement is what you want*/
alter table #MoveIns alter column Email VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
GO

/*Test*/
declare @cid varchar(10) = '1', @email varchar(2000) ='email 1'

/*The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.*/
select * from #MoveIns where @cid = CID AND @email = Email
```

---

If you still have errors make sure there are not other columns that are of type `text`. You can query your database tables using `sp_columns` or use the designer in the Management Studio.

Comment: I changed it to type `varchar(max)` but the code still doesn't work because of the Equals method. Can you please show me how to change my query so that it works?